# Infer snapshot data type from return type in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `FutureBuilder` with an API, and would like to infer the type of `snapshotData` from what is returned from the API, but I'm unable to do so as `snapshotData` is always `dynamic`.

See this code:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: SomeApi.fetchSomething(),
  builder: ((BuildContext context, snapshotData) {
  
    if (snap.data != null) {
      return Loading();
    } else {
      /* do stuff */
      return SomeWidget();
    }
  }
)
```

I'm aware that I can pass the `FutureBuilder` a type á la `FutureBuilder<SomeType>` which will make `snapshotData` play ball; but the API already knows what type it returns and I don't want to have to find and import the type I'm expecting from the API which is a separate library/package.

Is there any way to allow the `snapshotData` to infer the correct type via what is returned from the `future` value in `FutureBuilder`? Surely this would make it a more robust widget?

Comment: Yeah... this is a current limitation of the type system in Dart. It is going to be improved in next version of Dart (2.18) with the following change: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/d8d9e06804dbeca93a30cc5283d96baaed89d746/CHANGELOG.md#language-1

Comment: Use FutureBuilder<SomeType> and be happy that you are not coding JavaScript :)

Comment: @activout.se Actually it's situations like this where I realise that TypeScript is superior to Dart's native typing. Don't want to troll, just my personal opinion/experience.

Comment: @shennan no worries... I mean if this is the biggest problem you face, you are still in a good place :)

Comment: @activout.se It's a minor footnote on the list.